# The spider isn't finding any pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to run my first spider but struggling. I can get it to run but it is not finding any pages. If anyone has any ideas they would be much appreciated.
my code is:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from second_hotel.items import Website


class secondhotelSpider(Spider):
    name = "second_hotel_spider.py"
    allowed_domains = ["uk.hotels.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://uk.hotels.com/hotel/details.html?FPQ=6&WOE=1&q-localised-check-out=10/04/2017&WOD=1&q-room-0-children=0&pa=1&tab=description&JHR=9&q-localised-check-in=03/04/2017&hotel-id=128604&q-room-0-adults=2&YGF=14&MGT=7&ZSX=0&SYE=3",
        "https://uk.hotels.com/hotel/details.html?FPQ=6&WOE=1&q-localised-check-out=04/04/2016&WOD=7&q-room-0-children=0&pa=1&tab=description&JHR=8&q-localised-check-in=03/04/2016&hotel-id=424807&q-room-0-adults=2&YGF=2&MGT=1&ZSX=0&SYE=3",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="directory-url"]/li')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['name'] = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['description'] = site.xpath('text()').re('-\s[^\n]*\\r')
            items.append(item)

        print items
        return items
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it print at least this? [] - empty list

Comment: No, it is not printing the list.

Comment: This is the whole code you have? If yes, you don't call the method.

Comment: I have a Pipeline, settings and items files aswell. But this is all the code in this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your xpath expression, therefore `sites` variable is empty.

You may check your xpath via `scrapy shell`

```
scrapy shell 'https://uk.hotels.com/hotel/details.html?FPQ=6&WOE=1&q-localised-check-out=04/04/2016&WOD=7&q-room-0-children=0&pa=1&tab=description&JHR=8&q-localised-check-in=03/04/2016&hotel-id=424807&q-room-0-adults=2&YGF=2&MGT=1&ZSX=0&SYE=3'
In [4]: response.xpath('//ul[@class="directory-url"]/li')
Out[4]: []
```

or `inspect_response(response, self)` in `parse` method.

```
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
inspect_response(response, self)
```

`start_urls` pages don't contain elements with `[@class="directory-url"]`